# Sending out email from landing page without creating record in underlying data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, triggered-send

I would like to know if there is a way to send out an email from a landing page via triggered send, without creating additional records in the underlying data extension.

My current solution uses AMPScript to invoke a triggered send, which works fine, but my problem is that upon sending out the email, it creates a new record in the data extension. This is something I would like to avoid.

Some details about the scenario: There are two (let's call them A and B) triggered sends defined in the system. Both are using the same data extension in the background. (important)
Based on some conditions, an API call triggers one or the other. BUT in case it's A version, the user will have to visit a landing page which at some point will trigger the B version of the email.
This works fine, but creates an extra record in the underlying data extension.

So my question is: How can I prevent the extra record to be created when sending out the B version of the email from the landing page? (While making sure a record does get created when it's triggered directly via the API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a Triggered Send Data Extension in your Triggered Send Definitions is optional.  If you don't specify a data extension, then the records will not be added.  However, there are a few things to consider for your specific use-case.

1) You cannot remove a data extension from a Triggered Send Definition once one has been assigned.  You will need to define a new Triggered Send Definition and have you landing page call it to trigger the B version.

2) If you are passing additional attributes in your Trigger call, these attributes will need to exist as Profile attributes in All_Subscribers.  Another option is to have your second Triggered Send Definition write to a different data extension, which only contains request for the B version of the email.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's pretty much what I expected, but wanted to make sure. I will simply create another triggered send without a data extension assigned to it and do it that way. Might not be elegant, but should get the job done. :)

Comment: you can also set a primary key on the DE - this will make it update an existing record instead of adding a new one each time an email is sent.